# C# UDP send/sendAsync too slow

Tags: c#, performance, udp

I'm trying to send **many** small (~350 byte) UDP messages to different remote hosts, one packet for each remote host. I'm using a background thread to listen for responses

```
   private void ReceivePackets()
   {
       while (true)
       {
           try
           {
               receiveFrom = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, localPort);
               byte[] data = udpClientReceive.Receive(ref receiveFrom);
               // Decode message & short calculation
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Log("Error receiving data: " + ex.ToString());
           }
       }
   }
```

and a main thread for sending messages using

```
udpClientSend.SendAsync(send_buffer, send_buffer.Length, destinationIPEP);
```

Both `UdpClient udpClientReceive` and `UdpClient udpClientSend` are bound to the same port.
The problem is `SendAsync()` takes around 15ms to complete and I need to send a few thousand packets per second. What I already tried is using `udpClientSend.Send(send_buffer, send_buffer.Length, destination);`which is just as slow. I also set both receive/send buffers higher and I tried setting `udpClientSend.Client.SendTimeout = 1;` which has no effect. I suspect it might have to do with the remote host changing for every single packet? If that is the case, will using many UDPclients in seperate threads make things faster?
Thanks for any help!

Notes: 
Network bandwidth is not the problem and I need to use UDP not TCP.
I've seen similar questions on this website but none have a satisfying answer.

**Edit**

There is only one thread for sending, it runs a simple loop in which `udpClientSend.SendAsync()` is called.
I'm querying nodes in the DHT (bittorrent hashtable) so multicasting is not an option (?) - every host only gets 1 packet.
Exchanging `UDPClient` class with the `Socket` class and using `AsyncSendTo()` does not speed things up (or insignificantly).

I have narrowed down the problem: Changing the remote host address to some fixed IP & port increases throughput to over 3000 packets/s. Thus changing the destination address too often seems to be the bottleneck.

I'm thinking my problem might be related to [UDP "Connect"-Speed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567392/udp-connect-speed-in-c-sharp) and `UDPClient.Connect()` is slowing down the code. If so, is there a fix for this? Is it a language or an OS problem?

Comment: I don't know much about the performance of these methods, but the 15ms mention raises a possible issue. If you're timing this with something like GetTickCount() that clock has a resolution of about 15ms, and measuring the delay inaccurately could have you searching down the wrong path for a solution.

Comment: I don't see anything in `UdpClient` or `Socket` that should cause poor performance. Katie's explanation seems most likely.

Comment: How many packets per second do you measure?

Comment: Also, I can't speak for `UdpClient`, but you can have multiple outstanding sends when using the bare-metal method `Socket.SendToAsync` -- this would give you maximum throughput.

Comment: I'm using the Stopwatch class to measure time. 15ms is the average, most messages take less time but at least 3ms. Wireshark measures around 200packets/second of which only half are upstream. This seems to correspond roughly to the 15ms figure. @Cory Nelson: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, are you suggesting to use additional threads to call Socket.SendAsync() in parallel?

Comment: I'm suggesting having multiple outstanding sends. You don't need multiple threads to do so -- that would actually harm performance.

Comment: What about multicast or broadcast the packets?

Comment: Please show a _complete_ code example that demonstrates the claimed performance problem. There is just too much unknown about your scenario with the given code. If you send many datagrams in sequence (i.e. in a loop), in a single thread, what kind of throughput do you see? Measuring a single datagram's performance isn't going to tell you much at all about the overall performance of the network; there's too much other overhead going on, including thread context switching and processing of the individual event.

Comment: See edit. @Peter Duniho: This is exactly the throughput I was measuring in wireshark.

Comment: So it may be the overhead of calling `Connect()`. Have you tried using `Socket.SendTo()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using UdpClient Connect before sending? It's an optional step if you want to set a default host. Looks like you want to send to multiple destinations so you can set the remote host each time you call the Send method.

If you decide to remove the Connect method you may see an improvement, but it still looks like you have a bottleneck somewhere else in your code. Isolate the Send calls and measure time then start adding more steps until you find what's slowing you down.

```
        var port = 4242;
        var ipEndPoint1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.56.101"), port);
        var ipEndPoint2 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.56.102"), port);
        var buff = new byte[350];
        var client = new UdpClient();

        int count = 0;
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        while (count < 3000)
        {
            IPEndPoint endpoint = ipEndPoint1;
            if ((count % 2) == 0)
                endpoint = ipEndPoint2;

            client.Send(buff, buff.Length, endpoint);
            count++;
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```