# What does UDP socket connect() do in kernel

Tags: sockets, udp, connect

I was surprised by the connect() function for UDP. I read online and realized that it enables the send() function which does not require a destination address.
I would like to know what exactly does a UDP connect do in the kernel.

I found a similar question here
[UDP "Connect"-Speed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567392/udp-connect-speed-in-c-sharp)
but maybe some detail was left out in the answer

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing real fancy with connected udp sockets. It just means that socket name will include destination address, and as such, kernel will use this name when destination address is not provided. No more than typing shortcut for all intents and purposes.